# C# creating an iCal file

Tags: c#, icalendar

I try to create an iCal file using the Ical.Net NuGet package

I get an error "The type name 'event' could not be found"

As far as I understood the description of the Ical.Net NuGet package it should provide the type "event"..

I have this code:

```
//Ical.Net NuGet package
//
using Ical.Net;
using Ical.Net.CalendarComponents;
using Ical.Net.DataTypes;
using Ical.Net.Serialization;

public class iCal
{

    public iCal()
    {
        // create a new iCalendar object
        Calendar calendar = new Calendar();

        // create three events and add them to the calendar
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            
//--> here error : 'The type name 'event' could not be found
            //
            var evt = new Event       
            {
                Summary = $"Event {i + 1}",
                Description = $"This is event {i + 1}",
                Start = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i)),
                End = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).AddHours(1))
            };
```

Comment: Looking in the source repo and samples, there doesn't seem to be an `Event` type, are you sure it shouldn't be `CalendarEvent` ([source](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/master/src/Ical.Net/CalendarComponents/CalendarEvent.cs)) ?

Comment: Also, the name in the error is all-lowercase, the name in your code is capitalized. Please share both your actual code and the error.

Comment: `event` is a [C# Keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/). Since `iCal` may also be used by VB.NET (which is case-insensitive), this may be an issue. See  [Keywords (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/). The _event_ you're looking for is probably not called `Event` (or `event`). Refer to the documentation for the NuGet package.